# Some content are not getting written in the file

Tags: c, file

```
void BMIcalc(void)
 {
      float BMI,height,weight;
              
     FILE *fp;
     struct Data
     {
         char Name[10];
         int Age;
         char Gender;
     
     } D;
       
        fp= fopen("details.txt","w+");

        if(fp==NULL)
        {
            puts("file cannot be opened");
            exit(1);
        }
      
              

               printf("\nenter the height of the user (in cm) : ");
               scanf("%f",&height);
               
               printf("\nenter the weight of the user (in kg) : ");
               scanf("%f",&weight);

               height=height/100;
               height=height*height;
               BMI = weight / height ;

               printf("\n\n Your BMI is %.2f \n\n",BMI);

               if(BMI<=18)
               {
                   underweight();

               }

               if(BMI>=18&& BMI<=25)
               {
                   printf("volla!!! you are in great shape...keep it up.");
               }

               
               char choice;
               printf("\n\n do you want to save your data (y/n) :");
               scanf("%c",&choice);
              
            
               if(choice=='y')
            {
            
            printf("\n Enter the User details :");
            printf(" \n Name = ");
            scanf("%s",D.Name);
            printf("\n Age = ");
            scanf("%d",&D.Age);
            printf("\n Gender = ");
            scanf(" %c",&D.Gender);
            fputs(" Name =",fp);   fputs(D.Name,fp);
            fprintf(fp, "\n AGE = %d",D.Age);
            fprintf(fp, " \n Gender = %c",D.Gender);
            fprintf(fp,"\n height =",height);
            fprintf(fp,"\n weight =",weight);
            
            fputs("\n",fp);
        
            }

       fclose(fp);
```

It is not printing the height and weight in the file details.txt after writing fprintf for both height and weight. I don't know why it's happening and how to fix it.

Here is the link to the full code:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wrpey2b33f729XcC0u8HuujhA9qEDC7c?usp=sharing

Please share if there is any changes required in the code to get the program to work properly.

Comment: Doesn't there need to be a `%` in `fprintf(fp,"\n height =",height);` somewhere?

Comment: below is my linked code it not working properly please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
        fprintf(fp,"\n height =",height);
        fprintf(fp,"\n weight =",weight);
```

This outputs the strings "\n height =" and "\n weight =". You pass `height` and `weight` to `fprintf`, but nowhere do you ask that they be printed.

You probably meant:

```
        fprintf(fp,"\n height = %f",height);
        fprintf(fp,"\n weight = %f",weight);
```

Comment: Still the height section giving garbage value don't know why

Comment: @OnkarChougule What input do you give? What output do you expect? What output do you get?

Comment: I have given a float input of height 168.88  got a garbage value is 2.0800009 something but the weight get printed perfectly as it was entered.

Comment: @OnkarChougule What is the exact input you give (all value)? What is the output you expect?